# How do I hide the swiper pagination for specific slides in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pagination, swiper.js

I have some 10 slides in my page, and it is done using react swiper. So I need the pagination (in my case I have used bullets) to be hidden for the slides 1 and 10. Is there a way to hide those using js in react?

Comment: Can you provide a link to the exact component you're using? This will be very helpful. Also sharing your current source code to initialize the swiper will help people answer more quickly and thoroughly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution.

Use `swiper API`:

**1/2. Detect specific slides by index**:

Detect **if** `this` slide **index** is zero for example (`first slide`) by [realIndex](https://swiperjs.com/swiper-api#prop-swiper-realIndex) & [slideChange](https://swiperjs.com/swiper-api#event-slideChange) event than do something:

```
  swiper.on('paginationUpdate', function () {
    let realIndex = this.realIndex;
    if(realIndex == 0){
      console.log("hello first slide");
    }
  });
```

**2/2. Destroy/Init pagination by API:**

[swiper.pagination.init()](https://swiperjs.com/swiper-api#method-swiper-pagination-init)

[swiper.pagination.destroy()](http://%20https://swiperjs.com/swiper-api#method-swiper-pagination-destroy)

```
  swiper.on('slideChange', function () {
    let realIndex = this.realIndex;
    if(realIndex == 0){
      /* Destroy pagination if slide is 1 */
      this.pagination.destroy();
    }else{
      /* Initialize pagination */
      this.pagination.init();     
    }
  });
```

**Demo example**
(**In HTML - but use the idea/concept for [Swiper React](https://swiperjs.com/react)):

```js
const swiper = new Swiper('.swiper', {
    // Optional parameters
    loop: true,

    // If we need pagination
    pagination: {
      el: '.swiper-pagination',
    },

    // Navigation arrows
    navigation: {
      nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
      prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
    },
    on: {
    init: function () {
      console.log('swiper initialized');
      /* hide pagination on load */
      this.pagination.destroy();
    }
  },
  });

  swiper.on('paginationUpdate', function () {
    let realIndex = this.realIndex;
    if(realIndex == 0){
      /* hide pagination if slide is 1 */
      this.pagination.destroy();
    }else{
      /* else show */
      this.pagination.init();     
    }
  });
```

```css
html,
body {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background: #eee;
  font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #000;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.swiper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
}

.swiper-slide {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  background: #fff;
  /* Center slide text vertically */
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://unpkg.com/swiper@7/swiper-bundle.min.css"
      />

<!-- Slider main container -->
<div class="swiper">
  <!-- Additional required wrapper -->
  <div class="swiper-wrapper">
    <!-- Slides -->
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1 - Hide pagination</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2 - Show pagination</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3 - Show pagination</div>
    ...
  </div>
  <!-- If we need pagination -->
  <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>

  <!-- If we need navigation buttons -->
  <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
  <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>

</div>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/swiper@7/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>
```